# Reshape 2D numpy array into 4D array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, conv-neural-network

I have an y_train (4D)  matrix which content is (33, 224, 224, 1) where (n_images, n_pixels_y, n_pixels_x, n_bands) that needed to be transformed into a 2D vector using Flatten

now i need to do the inverse process and turn the 2D vector back to the 4D matrix with the same dimensions, what is the best way to do it?

I've been trying to use reshape but it's not being very effective

Ex:

```py
y_pred = modelo.predict(x_test)
print(y_pred.shape) #this results in the current shape that is (33, 50176)


img = np.reshape(y_pred[1], (33,224,224,1))
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.show() #this results in a error 'cannot reshape array of size 50176 into shape (33,224,224,1)'
```

Comment: you need to use np.reshape()

Comment: or expand the dims, np.expand_dims()

Comment: Are you trying to reshape the whole `y_pred` or just one image, `y_pred[1]`?  When you reshape you can't change the number of elements.  224*224 is 50176.

Comment: y_test is a set of neural network training, i need to convert at least one image back to the matrix in order to see the prediction

Comment: Regardless of what you want to do, `reshape` cannot change the total number of elements.  That's basic math.

Comment: Why not?  `np.reshape(y_pred, (33,224,224,1))`.  Or `np.reshape(y_pred[1], (224,224,1))`